# Cast from 'String?' to unrelated type 'MapViewController' always fails

Tags: swift

Я учу разработку и вот он мой код.

```
     `
     override func prepare(for segue:    UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    
    guard let identifier = segue.identifier,
          let mapVC = segue.identifier as? MapViewController
          else {return}
    
    
    mapVC.incomeSegueIndetifire = identifier
    if identifier == "showPlace"{
        mapVC.place.name = placeName.text!
        mapVC.place.location = placeLocation.text!
        mapVC.place.type = placeType.text!
        mapVC.place.imageData = placeImage.image?.pngData()
    }
    
} `
```

Я сделал как было в курсе но мне выдувки ошибку короче написано у меня в заголовке поста. Как это исправит?

Comment: Вы пишете по английски на русском Stackoverflow :(

Comment: @NSA-bot ну я могу перестирал и на русский если надо

Comment: @Роман переведите пожалуйста ваш вопрос на русский язык

Comment: @Andrew спасибо ответ нашёл. Переведу попозже я чёт подумал что я на английской версии

Comment: не забудьте пожалуйста, иначе его по итогу закроют из-за несоответствия

Comment: @Andrew усе, поправил.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

А если попробовать вот так? (к сожалению, нет сейчас Макбука под рукой :( )

```
guard let identifier = segue.identifier,
      let mapVC = segue.destination as? MapViewController // тут поменял на destination
      else {return}
```

Comment: Спасибо. Просто я не внимательный. Там было не identifier a destination

Comment: Рад что помогло, а то мне даже не проверить было ))